# orientdb sql update edge?

Tags: sql, hyperlink, orientdb, graph-databases

I have been messing around with orientdb sql, and I was wondering if there is a way to update an edge of a vertex, together with some data on it.

assuming I have the following data:
Vertex: Person, Room
Edge: Inside (from Person to Room)

something like:

```
UPDATE Persons SET phone=000000, out_Inside=(
    select @rid from Rooms where room_id=5) where person_id=8
```

obviously, the above does not work. It throws exception:

```
Error: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.id.ORecordId cannot be cast to com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.record.ridbag.ORidBag
```

I tried to look at the sources at github searching for a syntax for bag with 1 item,
but couldn't find any (found %, but that seems to be for serialization no for SQL).

(1) Is there any way to do that then? how do I update a connection? Is there even a way, or am I forced to create a new edge, and delete the old one?

(2) When writing this, it came to my mind that perhaps edges are not the way to go in this case. Perhaps I should use a LINK instead. I have to say i'm not sure when to use which, or what are the implications involved in using any of them. I did found this though:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/orient-database/xXlNNXHI1UE

comment 3 from the top, of Lvc@, where he says:

```
"The suggested way is to always create an edge for relationships"
```

Also, even if I should use a link, please respond to (1). I would be happy to know the answer anyway.

p.s.
In my scenario, a person can only be at one room. This will *most likely* not change in the future. Obviously, the edge has the advantage that in case I might want to change it (however improbable that may be), it will be very easy.

## Solution (partial)

(1) The solution was simply to remove the field selection. Thanks for Lvca for pointing it out!

(2) --Still not sure--

Answer (score 2):

`CREATE EDGE` and `DELETE EDGE` commands have this goal: avoid the user to fight with underlying structure.

However if you want to do it (a little "dirty"), try this one:

```
UPDATE Persons SET phone=000000, out_Inside=(
  select from Rooms where room_id=5) where person_id=8
```

Comment: Thanks! that does seem to work. However, any chance you can answer (2) as well?

Answer (score 0):

```
update EDGE Custom_Family_Of_Custom 
set survey_status = '%s', 
apply_source = '%s' 
where @rid in (
select level1_e.@rid from (
MATCH {class: Custom, as: custom, where: (custom_uuid = '%s')}.bothE('Custom_Family_Of_Custom') {as: level1_e} .bothV('Custom') {as: level1_v, where: (custom_uuid = '%s')} return level1_e
)
)
```

it works well

Comment: Please provide some explanations with your code as well.